# Выполнение литерала из строки полученной из Mongo в Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Всем привет! Надеюсь поможете и не засмеете ибо вопрос странный.
Для примера я получаю строки из монгодб "тест ${user} тест", есть ли какой то вариант кроме .replace , сделать так что бы ${user} принимало значение константы.

Comment: Если у тебя константа в коде создана с именем, которое внутри скобок и строка выделена не простыми кавычками, а обратным апострофом ` тест ${.... тогда содержимое в скобках будет принимать значение константы..

Comment: Это да, но монго же принимает строку только в простых кавычках и отдает респонс только в обычных кавычках